# Can the preprocessor tell if SystemVerilog is enabled?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I'd like to be able to write code like this:

```
`ifdef SYSTEMVERILOG_ENABLED
  .. systemverilog code here.
`else
 .. verilog-2001 equivalent code here.
`endif
```

But the SystemVerilog reference manual doesn't seem to reference any such standard predefined constant.  This seems like an oversight -- is there a simple way to do what I intend here?

Comment: Agreed.  The keyword specifiers were introduced so that legacy code could be parsed with a newer standard without having to change identifier names.  'do' popped up a lot as short for 'data out' but once SystemVerilog came around this became a keyword and would would no longer parse.  New code should simply avoid using reserved words in any of the standards.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there are compiler directives `begin_keywords "version_specifier"` and `end_keywords`, where:

```
version_specifier ::=
    1800-2009
  | 1800-2005
  | 1364-2005
  | 1364-2001
  | 1364-2001-noconfig
  | 1364-1995
```

Example from the LRM:

```
`begin_keywords "1364-2001" // use IEEE Std 1364-2001 Verilog keywords
module m2 (...);
reg [63:0] logic; // OK: "logic" is not a keyword in 1364-2001
...
endmodule
`end_keywords
```

This is covered in chapter 22.14 of IEEE 1800-2009.

Personally, I've never used these so I have no idea how well the tools support them.